# Spark Streaming: Writing number of rows read from a Kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Spark streaming job is reading events from a busy kafka topic. To get a sense of how much data is coming in per trigger interval, I want to just output count of rows read from the topic. I tried multiple ways of doing that but could not figure it out.

```
Dataset<Row> stream = sparkSession.readStream()
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServersString)
          .option("subscribe", topic)
          .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
          .option("enable.auto.commit", false)
//          .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
//          .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10000)
          .load();
      stream.selectExpr("topic").agg(count("topic")).as("count");
      //stream.selectExpr("topic").groupBy("topic").agg(count(col("topic")).as("count"));
      stream.writeStream()
            .format("console")
            .option("truncate", false)
            .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
            .start();
```

Comment: `stream.selectExpr` returns a new Dataset, which you're ignoring, so it's just writing what is being consumed

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the issue. Somehow I missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need

```
stream = stream.selectExpr("topic").agg(count("topic")).as("count");
```

And then you can print that